# How can I change the terminal line width in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.18.1 on Mac OSX and the integrated terminal seems to have a fixed width of 36 characters that doesn't increase when I make the terminal window wider.

How can change the number of characters per line in the terminal?
Is it possible to make the lines wrap based on the terminal window width?

Comment: Odd, when I check my terminal (inside VSC) the line breaks where the window ends. Have you done any modification to the OSX terminal layout?

Comment: I have the same problem, I use powershell in Visual Studio Code's terminal... so I tried to increase powershell line widht to 250 (it was 120). Didn't work :(

Comment: Can you do anything with or in the settings regarding the integrated terminal?  Go to Settings > Features > Terminal.  Then scroll to the setting for "Terminal > Integrated > Automation Shell: Osx" (ID = "terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx").  Does it make a difference whether your terminal.integrated.rendererType is "dom" or not?  (My integrated terminal's width adjusts with the window width, but it wraps, and I would like to find a way to have it be wide enough that it doesn't wrap, even if that means scrolling/panning to the right.)

Comment: 4 years later, with VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021), this should be supported. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69417181/6309)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is no option to disable word-wrap in VS Code integrated terminal

Actually, for VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021), there is:

> ### [Terminal / Toggle wrapped lines](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/29dc118bbe6431ef5c8815c6ddb88506b0e8b420/release-notes/v1_61.md#toggle-wrapped-lines):
>
> Toggle the terminal width between fitting the full contents and wrapped lines via `kb(workbench.action.terminal.sizeToContentWidth)` or using the tab context menu action `Toggle Size` to `Content Width`.
>
> [image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_61/terminal-content-width.gif]

Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: I guess this will be released on Oct 7th, 2021..

Comment: @AdityaHajare Indded. Two days from now.

Comment: This thing is available now.. In terminal, press ALT + z

Comment: @AdityaHajare Indeed VSCode 1.61 has been released. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks, the shortcut works. Is there also a way to disable line wrapping by default for new terminals?

Comment: @kapex This question "[Disable line wrap in Visual Studio Code integrated Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58542199/6309)" might help

Comment: Wish I could do this on VSCode's Jupyter notebook extension on the output it displays.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a fix to this currently per open issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74501

However in the above issue, user ultraGentle recommends `tput rmam` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, but the `tput rmam` command cuts off the line and you loose the text that normally gets wrapped. That's not what I want.

Comment: See also the idea `terminal.integrated.disableLineWrapping` on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48897 or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88005

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1:** As of now there is no option to disable word-wrap in VS Code integrated terminal ( internally running program like `bash` or `zsh` will get the same width as the vscode terminal area you can check with `echo "COLUMNS=$COLUMNS"` ) even popular terminal emulator like iTerm don't have this feature [see this open issue #1790](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1790)

now if you can not do this at vscode level you can try doing it on program lever ( like `bash` or `zsh` ) maybe there is some way by defining a setting in `bashrc` or `zshrc` but I can not find anything on internet

However there is a program which can make horizontal scroll available for you at program level and that is `less -S` you can pipe any output ( with help of `|` oprator ) in it like

```
echo " this is very long lorem ipsum text sldkfjdslfk jsdlfkj sldfkj sldfkj sdlfjs dlfkjsd flsd jfsdlkfsdlfkj slfkjs lflskdfjsldfjsdlfksdlfkjsdflksdjflsdkfj ssldfkjsdlkf jsdlfkj sdlfsjdlfksdf lsdfjk " | less -S
```

you can scroll horizontally with help of arrow key for more shortcut see

```
 h  H                 Display help.
 q  :q  Q  :Q  ZZ     Exit.
```

[image]

---

I am using version `1.42.1` and it works as expected maybe you can try updating it to the latest version

[image]

I also checked the configuration ( `command + ,` ) there wasn't any setting related to width of the integrated terminal

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work for me. @Tony, do you still have this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.42.1 and the text gets wrapped but the question is "How can I change the terminal line width in Visual Studio Code?" I would like to set it to e.g. 10000 characters so the lines don't break and don't wrap. I print huge pandas `DataFrames` and the printout gets totally unreadable when it gets wrapped. I need it to be printed as it is so I can use horizontal scroll and view all the data that was printed. SO I want to get rid of wrapping like @Jon Freed and others that commented the question.

Comment: @Tony  I have updated the answer please check if that solves your problem

Comment: [@Tripurari Shankar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6455628/tripurari-shankar): But how can I use it in VS Code when I run a Python script and it prints a huge pandas `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @Tony if you are talking about debug console there you can control word-wrap with `"debug.console.wordWrap": true` please note that debug console and integrated terminal is two different things and if you are running your script in shell then `lesss -S` will be always there it's vscode independent thing

Comment: @Tripurari Shankar: Thanks, I know those are two different things. I am looking for a solution for the internal Terminal in VSCode for running Python scripts and printing DatFrame (not for debugging) So something like `"terminal.integrated.wordWrap": false`

Comment: @Tony sadly that is not possible yet

Comment: Isn't it possible to configure and send the Terminal output to Debug Console when running a Python script?

Comment: I have found out that there is an option `"redirectOutput": true` I could use in `launch.json` to redirect the Terminal output to the Debug Console. This is for now a good workaround for me. Still giving you a vote-up for helping

Comment: I am new to VSCode and I make wrong conclusions... Redirecting to Debug Console is only possible when debugging with `"console": "integratedTerminal"` (that is where you can choose the options from `launch.json`) So still no solution...

Comment: @Tony can you share your `launch.json` ? if it's ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208137/discussion-between-tony-and-tripurari-shankar).

Comment: @Tony you can redirect the output in console and disable the word wrap there use `"console": "internalConsole", ` ( in launch.json) to redirect the output in console and use `"debug.console.wordWrap": false` to disable word-wrap in console

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to disable word-wrap in VS Code integrated terminal, but you can set an external terminal via `"console": "externalTerminal"` and there disable the word wrap or set the line width.

For example: On Windows click on top left corner to see the menu and select Properties, then Layout and uncheck the buffer checkbox and then increase the buffer to 4000.
On Linux try `setterm -linewrap off`