# Disable line wrap in Visual Studio Code integrated Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable line wrap in Visual Studio Code integrated Terminal?

I would like to do not see line breaking when output is too long.

Look how bad it looks.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to know how to disable line wrap in terminal in vscode, too.

Answer (score 34):

You can in terminal use `Alt` + `Z` keybinding to toggle between the wrap and unwrap.

There was an issue [#74501](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74501) with this before that was fixed.

Comment: i tried using this on my vscode (windows 10), it did not work

Comment: This shortcut seems to work only for line wrapping in the editor. It doesn't seem to affect the terminal for me.

Comment: @kapex what Visual Studio Code version under which OS are you using?

Comment: @SinaMobasheri My bad, I just tried again and now it works. Yesterday using Win11, latest VS Code in dev container bash shell it didn't. Whatever it was, I guess the restart fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Completely disabling line wrapping for embedded terminals in VSCode is not possible because the shell running within the terminal window always breaks lines to its visible width.

As of VSCode 1.61 (Sep 2021) you can set a wider virtual width of the terminal window. This reduces the amount of line wrapping the underlying shell is doing and gives you a nice scrollbar within VSCode.

To enable this, enter `Terminal: Set Fixed Dimensions` into VSCode's command palette.

[image: screenshot of the command palette showing the "Terminal: set fixed dimensions" entry]

More info at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_fixed-dimensions.

Comment: While this solves the problem, another bug causes ugly GUI problems when setting a large dimension (apparently over 2000).

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no such option, but it may be available in the future because of [#74501](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74501)

Comment: Maybe now fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/130777 For VSCode 1.61 (sept. 2021)