# Make terminal in VS Code horizontal scroll-able?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make the integrated Powershell terminal horizontal scroll-able?

I'm printing pretty formatted SQL tables, but if the columns are too wide, it tries to fit everything on the current size of the window, inserting newlines, making it not readable.

As a reference, I tried PyCharm. Also with Powershell terminal. There it is horizontal scroll-able and it works really nice.

I haven't found the setting in VS Code yet.

Comment: My answer was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542199/disable-line-wrap-in-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think xterm.js (which VS Code's integrated terminal is built on) supports horizontal scrolling. See https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/2544 and [the reply by maintainer Daniel Imms there](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/2544#issuecomment-550467386). Maybe VS Code could do something according to that reply to support it at the application level, but I'm not familiar with the technicalities to know.

On the UNIX side, you can disable wrapping by using `tput rmam`, but that generally just makes it so things that overflow the display width get cropped (no scrollbar). You could use a pager program like `less` to display the wide text and horizontally navigate it.